# How do I access contents of mountpoint directory before mount without unmounting?

Tags: linux, mount

I'm running a linux server and have an encrypted partition. After a reboot, I manually log into the server, enter the passphrase and mount it at `/home`.

Is there a way to access the content of `/home` before the mount without unmounting the encrypted partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--bind` option of mount.

```
mkdir /mnt/tmproot
mount --bind / /mnt/tmproot
ls /home # Still shows contents of mounted /home partition
ls /mnt/tmproot/home # pre-mount contents of mountpoint /home dir
```

Additionally mounting root partition this way will give you access to mountpoint directory contents in your root partition without their mounts, whilst also leaving existing mounts in place.